# Using VectorPlot3D gives me the following error: "Value of option PlotPoints -> {} is not an integer >= 2"

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

```
f[x, y] := {1 - ((20 - x)/20)^y}
scalarField = (1 - ((20 - x)/20)^y) - z       (*This is the same as f[x, y] - z, used later*)
vectorField = D[scalarField,  {{x, y, z}}]

In[98]:= v = VectorPlot3D[vectorField, {x, 0.001, 10}, {y, 0.001, 5}, {z, 0, 1}, 
                          RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, TrueQ[f[x, y] == z]], 
                          VectorPoints -> Automatic]
```

I get the following error:

```
VectorPlot3D::ppts: Value of option PlotPoints -> {} is not an integer >= 2.
```

I'm VERY new to Mathematica and the documentation doesn't really help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

What I want to happen is that I get only the vectors on the surface of `f[x, y]`, so the documentation says I should be using the RegionFunction property. The Region function property was giving me even MORE errors before I wrapped it in TrueQ (it was claiming f[x,y] == z wasn't boolean).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: function `f[x, y]` should be `f[x_, y_]`, but the problem is that `TrueQ[f[x, y] == z]` is always false. Hence there is no region to plot. It like writing `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, False]`

Comment: @Nasser Why is `f[x, y] == z` always False? There are values `(x, y, z)` for which `TrueQ[f[x,y] == z]` is `True`. For example: `TrueQ[f[3, 3] == {3087/8000}]`

Comment: It's really not a good error message, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to get the desired sampling:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, y_] := {1 - ((20 - x)/20)^y}
scalarField = (1 - ((20 - x)/20)^y) - z;
vectorField = D[scalarField, {{x, y, z}}];

r = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0.001, 10}, {y, 0.001, 5}, Mesh -> None, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 9, NormalsFunction -> None];

v = VectorPlot3D[
  vectorField, {x, 0.001, 10}, {y, 0.001, 5}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  VectorPoints -> 
   Cases[r, {_Real, _Real, z_Real}, Infinity],
  VectorScaling -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: A more direct way to get sampling: `r = Flatten[
  Outer[Flatten@{##, f@##} &, Subdivide[0.001, 10, 8], 
   Subdivide[0.001, 5, 8]],
  1]`.  The inner `Flatten` would be unnecessary if `f[x, y]` returned a scalar instead of a 1-vector.  But `Plot3D[]` will automatically handle singularities and holes in the domain of `f[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Why is f[x, y] == z always False?
```

The numbers are not exact. You could add tolerance. Without it, RegionFunction returns False, there was no case where `TrueQ[f[x, y] == z]` returned `True`.

```
scalarField = (1 - ((20 - x)/20)^y) - 
  z       (*This is the same as f[x,y]-z,used later*)
vectorField = D[scalarField, {{x, y, z}}]
f[x_, y_] := 1 - ((20 - x)/20)^y
epsilon = 0.1;
VectorPlot3D[vectorField, {x, 0.001, 10}, {y, 0.001, 5}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[f[x, y] - z] < epsilon], 
 VectorPoints -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could also make your `VectorPoints -> Fine` instead of automatic. But the whole reason for the error you are getting is that `TrueQ[f[x, y] == z]` returns False for all the sampling used as is.

For example

```
epsilon = 0.01;
VectorPlot3D[vectorField, {x, 0.001, 10}, {y, 0.001, 5}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, TrueQ[Abs[f[x, y] - z] < epsilon ]], 
 VectorPoints -> 30]
```

Returns

[image: Mathematica graphics]